# Actual and formal parameter lists differ in length

Tags: java, class, constructor

I was writing a Volume and Book class in Java, to help me better understand Constructors and Objects - basically the broader aspects of OOP. When I try to create a main class, I receive an error that states the following:

"constructor Volume in class Volume cannot be applied to given types;
 required: String, int, Book[]
 found: no arguments
 reason: actual and formal lists differ in length
----"

Here is the code I have so far.

First, the Volume class:

```
public class Volume extends Book{

public String volumeName;
public int numberOfBooks;
public Book[] books;

// Constructor with parameters
public Volume(String volumeName,int numberOfBooks,Book[] books){
    this.volumeName = volumeName;
    this.numberOfBooks = numberOfBooks;
    this.books = new Book[numberOfBooks];
}

// String representation of the Volume
public static String toString(Volume volume){
    String volumeDescription = "Here are the details of the selected Volume:\n";
    volumeDescription += "The volume's name is \"" + volume.volumeName + "\".\n";
    volumeDescription += "It contains " + volume.numberOfBooks + " books.\n";
    volumeDescription += "Here is a list of books it contains:\n";
    for(int i = 0; i < volume.numberOfBooks; i++){
        volumeDescription += "[" + i + "] " + volume.books[i];
    }
    return volumeDescription;
}

// Description of each book in the Volume
public static String getBookArray(Volume volume){
    Book[] listOfBooks = volume.books;
    String bookDescriptions = "Here is a description of each book in the Volume.\n";
    for(int i = 0; i < listOfBooks.length; i++){
        bookDescriptions += "Book #" + i + ":\n";
        bookDescriptions += "Title: " + listOfBooks[i].title + "\n";
        bookDescriptions += "Author: " + listOfBooks[i].author + "\n";
        bookDescriptions += "Number of pages: " + listOfBooks[i].numberOfPages + "\n";
    }
    return bookDescriptions;
}
```

}

And here is main, where I receive the above error I mentioned:

```
public class Volume_Main extends Volume{

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
}
```

}

I have the Constructor in Volume properly set up (to my understanding), but still receive this error. Any tips or suggestions? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why do you make your `Volume_Main` class extending `Volume`? Remove `extends Volume`.

Comment: What statement you add in main method to call construtor which throw error ??

Comment: When I extend it with Volume, doesn't that mean I'll have access to the Volume class? That's worked fine for me before with other programs I have written

Comment: Since your extending Volume and you didn't specify a constructor, the compiler will add the no arg constructor for you and hence call `super()` in it (call the no-argument constructor of the superclass). Since you don't have a no arg constructor in your Volume class, you get this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Java, every class has to have a constructor. In the case that you don't explicitly define one the compiler essentially inserts an empty constructor for you. Constructors also implicitly call the parameterless constructor of the parent class, if you haven't explicitly called a superclass constructor yourself. So your `Volume_Main` class has the following constructor:

```
public Volume_Main() {
    super()
}
```

However, the parent class of `Volume_Main` is `Volume`, and that has no parameterless constructor, so the compiler throws an error. There's probably no reason for `Volume_Main` to extend `Volume`, but at the very least you're going to have to explicitly define a parameterless class in `Volume`.

Comment: As compiler add parameter less contructor to sub-class so why it don't add in super class ??

Comment: @Youngistan It only adds the parameterless constructor if the class doesn't have an explicitly defined constructor. In this case, the `Volume` class (the parent class of `Volume_Main`) *does* have a constructor, but it takes parameters.

Comment: kk thnks for explanation

Comment: @AnthonyGrist What about the Constructor I made in the first place, with the three parameters? Can you please explain why that wasn't seen as the Constructor in Volume_Main? Thank you!

Comment: @user3380461 Because the compiler-created constructor only calls a parameterless constructor on the super class. That's the only constructor that is assumed to exist, because you either explicitly define it in your class (potentially along with other constructors) *or* the compiler inserts one for you. In the case of a constructor that does take parameters in the parent class, the compiler doesn't know what those values should be when calling it from the child class constructor and also doesn't know which of the constructors (if there are multiple) should be called.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist Thank you for the explanation, it makes much more sense now

Answer (score 0):

Or you remove `extends Volume` or you create a contructor with the same parameters in Volume_Main. Personally I think inhering from Volume in this case has no sense.

Answer (score 0):

Your Volume class constructor is a no arg constructor. And you are extending Volume class in Volume_Main class. By default it will look for no arg constructor in Volume class.

So in Volume_Main class you have to define constructor that will call proper constructor of Volume class.

Edit:

Two ways you can resolve this issue.

1) if you don't have any need to extend Volume class then you can remove `'extends Volume'` from Volume_Main class.

2) You can define a no arg constructor in Volume class that will call your defined parameterised constructor like

```
public Volume() {
  this(voulmeName, numberOfBooks, books);
}
```